# cakephp: how to make title and metas unique to each page?

Tags: cakephp

I have a project made in cakephp 2.2

It uses default.ctp layout where

```
<title>, <meta> are harde coded
```

so EACH page of my site **has same title and metas**

My goal (for SEO) is to **make title and meta unique for each page** (each controller)

What is the best way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Extending Views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#extending-views)

```
<?php
// in your view file
$this->assign('title', 'best title');

$this->start('meta');
echo $this->Html->meta('keywords', 'enter any meta keyword here');
$this->end();
?>

// in your layout file (default.ctp)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title><?php echo $this->fetch('title'); ?></title>
    <?php echo $this->fetch('meta'); ?>
    </head>
    // rest of the layout follows
```